# How to check route by coordinates

Tags: java, algorithm, polygon

I've got a problem: I have two coordinates (start and end point positions) and a polygon. I want to check whether this route is (1) from outside to inside of the polygon, (2) from inside to outside, (3) only inside, or (4) only outside.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: You probably have an [algorithm for that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon). Did you try to implement it?

Comment: Google for *point in polygon algorithms*.

Answer (score 1):

You are lucky! Java contains a `Polygon` class which has a method [`contains(double x, double y)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html#contains%28double,%20double%29). Use it!

Answer (score 0):

See this page:
http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html

This function is taken from there.

It is based on the observation that a test point is within a polygon if when projected on the y-axis it's x value is below odd number of polygon edges. Works for both convex and concave polygons.

```
int pnpoly(int nvert, float *vertx, float *verty, float testx, float testy)
{
  int i, j, c = 0;
  for (i = 0, j = nvert-1; i < nvert; j = i++) {
    if ( ((verty[i]>testy) != (verty[j]>testy)) &&
     (testx < (vertx[j]-vertx[i]) * (testy-verty[i]) / (verty[j]-verty[i]) + vertx[i]) )
       c = !c;
  }
  return c;
}
```